# Check if a model has data, within the view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

**QUESTION**

How do I safely and efficiently check if a view model has been populated with data, within the view itself?

**EXPLANATION**

I'm passing in a model to a view like so;

```
return View(response.Success ? (SalesDashboardViewModel)response.Model : new SalesDashboardViewModel());
```

Now, the view either has a fully populated view model with all the data, or, if the view model wasn't populated correctly, it may have an empty 'SalesDashboardViewModel'. If the second case is true, when I call `@Model.CountOfUsers` in the view for example, I will get a `null object reference` error.

How, in the view, would I go about checking if this is empty or not, other than checking if one of it's properties is null (due to the fact the properties may change).

**FULL CODE BREAKDOWN**

*// Controller*

```
public ActionResult SalesDashboard(){
    var response = DashboardService.BuildSalesViewModel(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    return View(response.Success ? response.Model : new SalesDashboardViewModel());
}
```

*// Populating the SalesDashboardViewModel*

```
public CustomResponseModel BuildSalesViewModel(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            CustomResponseModel response;
            var vm = new SalesDashboardViewModel();
            response = GetCountOfSuspectsAddedThisMonth(userId);
            vm.NoSuspectsAddedThisMonth = response.Success ? (int)response.Model : throw new Exception(response.Reason);
            response = GetCountOfProspectsAddedThisMonth(userId);
            vm.NoPropectsAddedThisMonth = response.Success ? (int)response.Model : throw new Exception(response.Reason);
            response = GetCountOfCustomersNotContactedRecently(userId, 12);
            vm.NoCustomersNotContactedRecently = response.Success ? (int)response.Model : throw new Exception(response.Reason);
            response = GetTopProspects(userId, 10);
            vm.TopProspects = response.Success ? (List<Prospect>)response.Model : throw new Exception(response.Reason);
            return new CustomResponseModel { Success = true, Model = vm };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new CustomResponseModel
            {
                Success = false,
                Reason = e.Message,
            };
        }
    }
```

If there is a better way of going about this then I'm open to suggestions. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Safe Navigation Operator (?.) to access the properties, if you are not sure that they will have the value.

```
@Model?.CountOfUsers
```

Find more details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/).

Comment: That's a great little helper, thank you. I'll be sure to use that regularly!